# $.NSUserNotificationCenter('defaultUserNotificationCenter') returns null

Tags: node.js, nodobjc

I am trying to fire up a notification to the Notification Center through `node` and `NodObjC` and
the problem is:

```
    $.NSUserNotificationCenter('defaultUserNotificationCenter')
```

returns always `null` instead of an object to be abled to call the `deliverNotification` method ?

Does anyone has experience with `NodObjC` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting up a hook to provide the bundle id. Here is the demo code:

```
var $ = require('NodObjC');
$.import('Cocoa');

// hook the bundle id
($.NSBundle).getInstanceMethod('bundleIdentifier').setImplementation(function(value) {
  return $('com.example.app1');
});

// test
var center = $.NSUserNotificationCenter('defaultUserNotificationCenter');
console.log(center); // output: <_NSConcreteUserNotificationCenter: 0x103821e90>
```